# Log android app settings to GoogleAnalytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, user-tracking

I have android application where I use Google Analytics. I would like track app settings per user. For example user can select language and background color. I would like see report with percent distribution between locales and between background color like example bellow.

Locales :

- 50% en-us
- 50% en-gb

Backgrounds :

- 50% green
- 20% blue
- 30% red

When user change this value I would like propagate it to Analytics dashboard and rewrite old value.
Do you have hint how solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With an Android application, you'll want to use custom dimensions & metrics with the GA Mobile SDK:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/customdimsmets

Use a user-level custom dimension to track the information you want.  Name options would be "locale" and "background" and the value options would be the available choices.

When a user changes the value of the locale or background setting, the custom dimension for that user will get updated.